# Activating separate functions based on the result of a function that posts information from a Form

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm a bit of a novice with the implementation of multiple functions. However, I have a form where people can enter information which when submitted is posted to where I am collating the information. My code at the moment is:

component.html

```
          <form name="hello"(ngSubmit)="onSubmit(helloForm); helloForm.reset();closeModal('custom-modal-2');openModal('custom-modal-3')" #helloForm="ngForm">
            <input type="text" class = "box" placeholder="Name" name="name" ngModel required #name="ngModel"><br>
             <input type="text" class = "box" placeholder="Email" email name="email" ngModel required #email="ngModel">
             <re-captcha (resolved)="resolved($event)" siteKey="key"></re-captcha>
             <br><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
         </form>
```

component.ts

```
export class HelloDetailsComponent {public pageTitle = 'Contact Me';

constructor(private modalService: ModalService, private http: HttpClient) {}
resolved(captchaResponse: string) {
  console.log(`Resolved captcha with response: ${captchaResponse}`);
}

openModal(id: string) {
    this.modalService.open(id);
}

closeModal(id: string) {
    this.modalService.close(id);
}

onSubmit(helloForm: NgForm) {
  if (helloForm.valid) {
    const email = helloForm.value;
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    this.http.post('formsent',
      {Name: email.name, Email: email.email},
      { 'headers': headers }).hello(
        response => {
          console.log(response);
        }
      ); 
  } 
}
```

At the moment, when I press the submit button without filling out the form, the openModal('custom-modal-3') appears.

I would like to change this so that it only appears when the form is submitted and implement a separate modal for when the form is incomplete. Does anyone have any ideas?